# I need recommendations on how to create a SQL Server user for a web application

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, security

Within the company where I work we have a main system created in .NET and that uses SQL Server. Each site has its own site in IIS and its database within the same SQL Server. When each site is installed or updated it executes scripts and store procedures so it needs certain permissions. They are currently using the `sa` user to do this and for me it is a security error.

I would like you to recommend which server role and user I should use. I had thought about creating a new server role that can only create and modify databases, then create a user that has that role, map that user to all the databases and grant it the execute, insert, update and delete permissions but There are concepts that I am not clear about.

I have an example:

```
CREATE SERVER ROLE "server role"

GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO "server role";
GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO "server role";

CREATE LOGIN "user" WITH PASSWORD = 'password';

ALTER SERVER ROLE "server role" ADD MEMBER "user";`

-- Get list of databases
DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(255);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
     SELECT name
     FROM sys.databases
     WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name;

-- Map user to all databases except master
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
     SET @sql = 'USE [' + @db_name + ']; CREATE USER "user" FOR LOGIN "user";
     EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

     FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name;
END

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Comment: If the (web) appplication is using it's own `LOGIN` to create the databases, then a `LOGIN` with the `dbcreator` server role would make sense; then when it creates the databases it's automatically the owner, is mapped to the `dbo` `USER` and has full `db_owner` permissions. If it should have less permissions than that, someone else should be creating the database(s) and creating it a `USER` in the database will the minimal permissions it needs.

Comment: The syntax you've provided, however, isn't valid, and is open to injection. You use backticks, which isn't part of the T-SQL dialect, you don't close your single quotes (`'`) in your `SET @SQL` statement, and `'[' + @db_name + ']'` is open to injection (if you want to inject an object name, use `QUOTENAME`).

Comment: Who is in charge of creating the site, configuring IIS, copying the binaries, creating the database with all its structure, etc. It is another web system that we have.
From what I understand from what you tell me, I should have this system create the database with a user with a dbcreator role and he automatically becomes the owner of that database.

Comment: *"I should have this system create the database with a user with a dbcreator role and he automatically becomes the owner of that database."* That isn't what I said, no. I said *If it needs to that, do...*

Comment: _When each site is installed or updated it executes scripts and store procedures so it needs certain permissions_ does it create a database? I'll assume not. _I had thought about creating a new server role that can only create and modify databases_ db_owner is a database specific (not server wide) role that would be more appropriate. In fact if all web site have the `sa` password and they are meant to be client specific, that is a _very big_ issue. You could  just hack one web site and gain access to all databases and invisibly change data.